# Is it possible to sync multiple radio buttons on a QGIS 2.0 custom feature form?

Tags: qgis, pyqt

Is it possible to sync multiple radio buttons on a QGIS 2.0 custom feature form to one attribute? For example i have three choices (owner, renter, and other) and choosing the radio button would fill the same field with the button of choice.

Comment: I think the out-of-the-box solution would be to use a dropdown list with pre-filled values. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @underdark It's the current fallback, but it's a detail that would allow this form to have the exact appearance of another form we've developed. I find the radio buttons have a good user response.